# Create Excel Form Control - Button

Tags: .net, excel, openxml, closedxml, spreadsheetlight

I have a project that is using the following three libraries to access XLSM documents

- Open XML
- Closed XML
- Spreadsheet Light

I'd now like to create a Form Control (a button) that will have a macro assigned to it (just a public function I've created with VBA).

How do I do this? Is one library better than another? (or do any of them let me do it besides Open XML)

I am using C# if anyone uses specific syntax :)

Comment: Not possible with ClosedXML.